# Bash send mail only if file contains string

Tags: string, bash, email, search

A process creates a new log file each time it runs. If the log file contains the string ERROR, I want it to be emailed to me using mail. I do not want an email if there were no errors.

Created alias named admins in .mailrc for recipients

This command works fine to always send the log via email:

```
cat /home/user/import.log | mail -s 'Import Error Log' admins
```

Now then what I want is a concatenated command to check if the file contains 'ERROR' then run the mail command only if it does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you got down voted. It would be nice if the person who gave you a -1 explains why.

Answer (score 1):

```
if fgrep ERROR /home/user/import.log; then
    mail -s 'Import Error Log' admins
fi
```