# send mail if number range present

Tags: bash, email

I've read this bash script here:

[Bash send mail only if file contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165967/bash-send-mail-only-if-file-contains-string)

but it does not test for number values:

```
if fgrep ERROR /home/user/one-number.txt; then
mail -s 'Import Error Log' admins
fi
```

this almost does what I want but I need to only send if `one-number.txt` contains one number which is either greater than 270 or less than 90, AND I need to send to a large list of people.

Bash not required.  Php, python, perl can work, too.

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
subject="Alert";
i=$(cat file_with_1_number.txt) ;
if [$i > 269 && $i < 361  ||  $i > 0 && $i < 91; then
mail -s $subject admin@example.com < file.txt;
fi
```

Comment: What did you do to try and solve this? All you did was find a piece of code online post it here and expect someone to fix it for you.

Comment: You need to show the structure of the input file. There are basically 2 main wais. Either you extract the number and then compare the value in the script or you use a regular expression which matches the unwanted numbers.

Comment: subject="Alert";
    i=$(cat report.txt) ;
    if [$i > 269 && $i < 361  ||  $i > 0 && $i < 91; then
      mail -s $subject admin@example.com < file.txt;
    fi                                                                        scratching my head this does not work.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors. There needs to be a space after `[` and a closing `]` as well. You cannot use `||` inside `test` so you need a second pair of square brackets for the second test. But the syntax in @bryn's answer is less cumbersome if you are happy with a Bash-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your last attempt is not too far off. This works:

```
subject="Alert"
i=$(cat file_with_1_number.txt)
if (( $i > 269 && $i < 361 )) || (( $i > 0 && $i < 91 ))
then
  mail -s $subject admin@example.com < file.txt
fi
```

`((..))` is used to tell bash it's an arithmetic expression (since you are using arithmetic expressions). Also grouping is important when you check multiple ranges in one go.